# Run system commands from QML App

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, c++, qml

I want to run a system command from inside my application. It's suppose to run a command on a remote server using SSH. But that's not really the point. The point is that I don't know how to run any kind of command from the app. I asked in the mail list and they referred me to build a QML extension using C++. But I don't know C++ and it seems that I have to learn so much only to run a simple command.

In Python (as in PHP) it's easy to run a system command. Is there any other way of doing it in my Touch app, or is there someone that could help me even more? Or perhaps have a better solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you remove all the content not having to do with the core of your question, such as the "Minecraft Server", How you are learning this "Just for fun", etc? The reason I ask is because these details are beside the issue and pretty distracting, respectfully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't something that QML supports, the typical answer is to write a C++ plugin to handle that kind of thing.

However, the SDK team is planning out various extensions to provide to QML app developers, and this may be something that they implement in a generic plugin that you can use.

Comment: That would be much appreciated! I've instead started to look for a way to call a Python script, but I can only find a Python script that runs QML, and not the other way around.

Comment: What I finally did was that I made some changes to my webui for the same function as the new app, and pull the info I need from that using XML. Pretty neat.

Comment: I've tried the QProcess Launcher concept in 14.04 and it works fine: http://askubuntu.com/a/446736/20275

Comment: @mhall119 Please correct me if I am wrong, but you can not actually do this with QML on the phone because of AppArmor. It will prevent you from doing this.

Answer (score 11):

**Update: For 14.04 see the much simplified answer by int_ua.**

**Original Text:**

At http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=87580 there is a basic overview of how to add the extension to QML. I decided to give it a shot using the ubuntu-sdk instead, which is slightly different. I'll document below.

For this project I selected *Ubuntu Touch/Simple UI with C++ Backend* in QtCreator. This creates a project with two separate parts, the backend and the touchui frontend written in QML. To the backend we are going to add two files for the Launcher class.

launcher.h:

```
#ifndef LAUNCHER_H
#define LAUNCHER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>

class Launcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Launcher(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString launch(const QString &program);

private:
    QProcess *m_process;
};

#endif // LAUNCHER_H
```

launcher.cpp:

```
#include "launcher.h"

Launcher::Launcher(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_process(new QProcess(this))
{
}

QString Launcher::launch(const QString &program)
{
    m_process->start(program);
    m_process->waitForFinished(-1);
    QByteArray bytes = m_process->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString output = QString::fromLocal8Bit(bytes);
    return output;
}
```

This class simply uses QProcess to execute a program, waits for it to finish, reads its stdout, and returns it as a string.

Next we need to modify backend/backend.cpp to include the class. This requires two lines. Append an include:

```
#include "launcher.h"
```

and in **BackendPlugin::registerTypes** add a line:

```
qmlRegisterType<Launcher>(uri, 1, 0, "Launcher");
```

There should already be a line for MyType, which is the included example. After this we should be able to build the backend. The only thing that remains is to use it in the main.qml file. For this I added a line:

```
Launcher { id: myLauncher }
```

and to the Button's onClick handler, set:

```
myType.helloWorld = myLauncher.launch("date");
```

At this point all that remains is to start it up and test it out. Here is where I ran into a problem, since QtCreator doesn't seem to set everything up properly by default. As I workaround, in the terminal navigate to your QtCreator project directory and:

```
mkdir -p Ubuntu/Example
```

Then copy the libUbuntuExample.so file from ProjectBuildDir/backend to Ubuntu/Example, and the qmldir file from ProjectName/backend/qmldir. Then you can run:

```
qmlscene -I . ProjectName/touchui/main.qml
```

I'm sure there is probably a simple way to rig this all up so Build/Run just works.

Comment: It's now just works in 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/446736/20275

Answer (score 7):

### Ubuntu 14.04

The concept of QProcess Launcher type is now working without problems in Trusty with `ubuntu-sdk-team` PPA. Just create `QML Extension Library + Tabbed UI` project ([don't use hyphens in project name yet](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bug/1306872)), replace contents of

#### `mytype.h`

```
#ifndef LAUNCHER_H
#define LAUNCHER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>

class Launcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Launcher(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Launcher();
    Q_INVOKABLE QString launch(const QString &program);

protected:
    QProcess *m_process;
};

#endif // LAUNCHER_H
```

#### `mytype.cpp`

```
#include "mytype.h"

Launcher::Launcher(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_process(new QProcess(this))
{

}

QString Launcher::launch(const QString &program)
{
    m_process->start(program);
    m_process->waitForFinished(-1);
    QByteArray bytes = m_process->readAllStandardOutput();
    QString output = QString::fromLocal8Bit(bytes);
    return output;
}

Launcher::~Launcher() {

}
```

and change `qmlRegisterType` in the `backend.cpp` to

```
qmlRegisterType<Launcher>(uri, 1, 0, "Launcher");
```

Next, just clean all `MyType` remains from QML files and add

```
        Rectangle {

          Launcher {
             id: qprocess
          }

          Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qprocess.launch("which bash")
          }
        }
```

wherever you like and

```
import projectname 1.0
```

in the beginning.

#### Optional

I also use this wrapper:

```
function exec(command) {
    return qprocess.launch("sh -c \"" + command + " < /dev/null \"")
}
```

If you need root access, add `pkexec`.

Comment: I would just like to confirm that this solution worked excellently for me. Whatever commands you input, its output is displayed in the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to know a lot about c++ to get access to terminal commands. Just put the following in any file ending with .cpp, for instance runPython.cpp.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    system("cd /home/user/path/to/script");
    system("python3 myScript.py");
    return 0;
}
```

All you have to find out now is how to get the c++ code running in QML but I'm sure that's very well documented.

Note that you can add any linux command you like by following the same syntax `system("linux command");`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You shall use **PlasmaCore.DataSource** with the engine "**executable**", as in this [example](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-lib/blob/d0b3329cb186b4cf6d412b438406ee3ec4190bcc/package/contents/ui/lib/AppletVersion.qml#L15).

Mind that the call is **asynchronous**. Hence the command sends a **signal** when it finishes, and a different part of the code picks the signal and continues with the next step you want to perform.