# How can I run a command from a qml script?

Tags: application-development, c++, iptables, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I'm working on an Ubuntu Touch app that needs to modify iptables and do various other things that requires interaction with the command line. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288494/run-system-commands-from-qml-app) and I understand that it must be done with a C++ plugin or a possible future extension in the SDK. Is there any such extension available now? And can someone elaborate on how I can use C++ to run a command from qml?