# Imports for executing system commands?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

QML at the moment lacks the ability to execute basic system commands. What libraries or functions can be imported to add this functionality to a .qml file?

Comment: Didn't you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/a/314095/169736

Comment: I suspect there is no answer at the moment for a library that you can just import. That question more or less asks for a work around.

Comment: Well, you can always ask in SO for doing that in C++ which seems like the only way to go about it.

Comment: From what I understand, the ubuntu sdk team will eventually be adding this functionality, although that is speculation from another comment I read. I can delete the question if you wish, but I was hoping to keep it open say if this ever does become thrown in.

Comment: Nah, if you ever find the answer, just post it to the other question ;)