# How to download and parse a gzipped xml file with qml in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml, xml

Currency converter [tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/building-your-first-qml-app/) is very useful in explaining how to download and parse an xml file through XmlListModel, but it seems it is not possible to parse a gizipped file in this way.
How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always `gunzip` it.

```
cat [file] | gunzip > file.xml
```

That will take the contents of the file, decompress them, and place them in file.xml.  You should be able to parse that just like any old plain XML out there.

Comment: It seems [it is possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288494/run-system-commands-from-qml-app) to run command line tools in Ubuntu Touch with C++, though I'd like a simpler way.

Comment: I mean run this command in Terminal, then process the new file.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear but I would like to write an app that can download and parse a gizipped xml file.

Comment: Aha.  Then you will need to implement gunzip into your code.