# KDE widget - run commands

Tags: kde, application-development, plasma-5, widgets

I'm looking for a way to run commands in a widget I'm trying to develop.

So far I've come across the `org.kde.kio.KRun`, which should be an interface to the kRunner. From the [few examples I have seen](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&ei=92pQXKXfKsaRsAeQ16L4Dw&q=%22import+org.kde.kio%22+site%3Agithub.com&oq=%22import+org.kde.kio%22+site%3Agithub.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31416.36163..36387...0.0..0.475.7105.4-16......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......35i39j33i160.1QGc5sKG7YQ), I only found that `KRun` has the following methods: `openUrl, openService` (which are not useful for running commands). I've tryed googling about it, but [the only resource I've found is this one](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kio/html/classKRun.html) which seems to be very different from the `org.kde.kio.KRun` used in the widgets.

How can I run a command from a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your widget is using the C++ then you could write a C++ plugin to handle the execution of the commands: [Run system commands from QML App](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288494/run-system-commands-from-qml-app)

If your widget is a QML only then you could use the PlasmaCore. An example plasma widget: https://store.kde.org/p/1166510/